# Can I use only Drawer and Tab Navigator without creating Stack Navigator in React?

Tags: react-native, navigation

The question is simple. I didn't see any example usage, therefore I am asking. Many thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes, you can!"

The long answer is "This is not practical"

You can create `TabNavigator` and `DrawerNavigator` only and call the `TabNavigator` inside `DrawerNavigator` in `NavigationContainer`, something like this:

```
import Tabs from "./src/navigation/tabs";
//....

render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Tabs"drawerContent={(props) => (<DrawerContent {...props} />)}>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Tabs" component={Tabs} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
```

But here if you have suppose 3 tabs - Home, Profile, Settings, and you want multiple pages inside each tabs, for example:

**Home** >> *Dashboard, Notifications*

**Profile** >> *View Profile, Edit Profile*

**Settings** >> *General Settings, Notification Settings, Contact Us*

At such situation, `StackNavigator` will be required so that each tab will have stack of multiple screens.